# How to get the value of property of protected property object through reflection at runtime?

Tags: php

I have an object created at runtime. It has a protected property, which is also an object created at runtime. This property object has a protected property, of string type, the value of which I need to get.

```
<?php

class A
{
    // will be set at runtime
    protected $s = 'hello';
}

class B
{
    // will be set at runtime
    protected $a;

    public function setA(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}

// for example, somewhere in the library
$a = new A();
$b = new B();
$b->setA($a);

// I have $b returned from some library method call

$r = new ReflectionObject($b);

// How to get 'hello'?
```

Documentation on the Reflection is rather sparse, can anyone help me here?

Comment: As you're after an instance property ($b is an instance) value rather than a class value, you should be looking at `ReflectionObject` rather than `ReflectionClass`

Comment: Why are you using Reflection to do this? Why not just `$b->getA()->getS();`

Comment: @MarkBaker, I can get a property with `getProperty` but how to extract the value of its property?

Comment: @Jessica, because these classes does not have getters for these properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      // for example
    $a = new A();
    $b = new B();
    $b->setA($a);

    $r = new ReflectionClass($b);
    $property = $r->getProperty("a");
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    $a = $property->getValue($b);

    $r = new ReflectionClass($a);
    $property = $r->getProperty("s");
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    $s = $property->getValue($a);
```

little bit tricky way, and even not sure is it needed, but it works now.

Comment: Doesn't work: `ReflectionException: Property s does not exist`